# Payout All Items in Mapping

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, mapping

I want to payout multiple addresses in one function call but I am trying to avoid using an array if possible.

```
 struct Receiver {
    address receiver;
    bool paidOut;
    bool isWinner;
 }


mapping(address => Receiver) public receivers;
```

Is there anyway I can payout all addresses registered in this mapping all together? Or do i need to use an array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array or some sort of indexing in the mapping to be able to do so. If you choose the indexing option you would still have to do the iteration on the application side and call the payout function for each member of the mapping.

Solidity file:

```
struct Receiver {
    address receiver;
    bool paidOut;
    bool isWinner;
 }
    
mapping(uint => mapping(address => Receiver)) public receivers;

function payout(uint index, address payer) public payable{
    //get the one Im working on
    Receiver receiver = receivers[index][payer];
   //...Some logic
}
```